# Extract WAV file from Bytes Array

Tags: java, file, audio, wav, riff

After sending a REST request the server brings back a really long string like this:

`RIFF\nt WAVEfmt ...(a lot of extra characters)`

This is supposed to be a .wav file.
From there I get a byte array using Java:

`byte[] audio = restResponse.getResponseBody().getBytes();`

Which returns something like this:

`[82, 73, 70, 70, 10, 116, 32, 0, 87, 65, 86, 69, 102, 109, 116, 32, 18...`

After that I write that array into a file:

`FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/temp.wav"), audio);`

The problem is, I've tried 2-3 audioplayer + importing the raw data to Audacity (tried different frequencies, channels...) but all I hear is static.

Comment: The original bytes have been encoded somehow to be represented as a string, you have to know how it was encoded to properly decode it (e.g Base 64 ).

Comment: Also, be sure to strip off the "RIFF\nt WAVEfmt " from in front of the actual bytes.

Comment: Please share the code you use to send request.
Without code sample nobody can help you.

@Steve11235 Bad idea. This just corrupt the data, nothing more.

Comment: In C, a string is used to contain a sequence of bytes.  In Java, a String is not suitable for holding bytes; converting bytes to and from Strings will *corrupt* the bytes.  Do not use String at all.  Always use byte arrays to hold bytes.

Comment: If you look at the byte sequence in the post, it starts with the codes for the characters R I F F \n, etc. I suspect that the actual WAV content is following that header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VGR said (thanks a lot!), the problem was the way the Rest client was converting bytes into a String.

By using Apache's HttpClient I was able to get the response bytes correctly.

> byte[] response = method.getResponseBody();
>
> FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/temp.wav"), response);